# Am I doing it right C# regarding parsing using delegate?

Tags: c#

I want to parse string into version numbers using delegate. The delegate requires a string as an argument and produces integer array as an output.

There are two errors

> Error CS0136  A local or parameter named '`arrayString`' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
>
> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<int>`' to '`int`'

```cs
namespace TEST
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate int Parsing(string parsee);
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Parsing parsee = new Parsing(Parse);
            Console.WriteLine(); 
        }

        public static int Parse(string arrayString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write the version numbers : ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
             string[] arrayString = input.Split('-');
            List<int> listInt = new List<int>();
            foreach (string i in arrayString)
            {
                listInt.Add(Convert.ToInt32(i));
            }
            listInt.ToArray();
            foreach (var item in listInt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            return listInt;
        }
    }
}
```

I am a noob.

Comment: The error messages are very explicit in what's wrong: 1) you're trying to declare `arrayString` twice for the same method. 2) A list is not a single integer. Also, `listInt.ToArray();` is pointless since you're not using the array it returns.

Comment: How should i be correcting it?

Comment: 1. Don't declare the same variable twice. You're not even using `string arrayString`, and then you're creating `string[] arrayString` with the same name. 2. Change your method signature to match what you're returning.

Comment: Is this the correct way to parse string into version number using delegate? Sorry for asking stupid questions, but I am new to c#

Comment: `listInt.ToArray();` won´t **convert** your list to array, it will **create a new array** from your list. So when you don´t assign the result of `ToArray` to a variable, it´ll be GCed imediately. Furthermore your `listInt` is surely a **list**, not a single int, even if it contains only a single element - which isn´t obviousl to me. So which element from the list do you want to return here?

Comment: How to make it right? May you please edit it?

Comment: It's not possible to answer if this is the correct way to parse a version number, since we don't know how your version number is formatted. Remember also that there are often numerous ways to achieve one task "correctly".

Comment: basically the task is to parse string into version numbers using delegate and further delegate requires string as an argument and produces an integer array as an output

Comment: version numbers are like 1.00.1.6 .

Comment: Your code definitely won't do that since you're splitting on `-` and not `.`.  You might want to see if the [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8) class suits your requirements.

Comment: May you change it so that i can understand what you mean to? Sorry for asking stupid stuff. I`m new

Comment: I did it because I have to perform operations on integers like comparing and adding

Comment: How should `1.0.0.1.6` be converted to a **single** ineteger? That´s completely unclear to me.

Comment: we can use array to store it. and access it by index

Answer (score 0):

The identifier "arrayString" is defined twice.

Local variables as well as arguments are not allowed to be defined with the same name, otherwise accessing the identifier would have ambiguous meaning.

As long as the `Parse` method is named "parse", it should act as-is. It takes an argument as input and outputs the produced result, which is the only duty of it. while `Console.ReadLine` or `Console.WriteLine` are not a part of "Parse" but "Input".

You need more learning on the basic syntax and the built-in types before you start learning delegate.

The solution that maybe matches your requirement as a demo is:

```cs
namespace Test
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        internal static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write the version numbers : ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            var results = ParseInts(input.Split('-'), ParseInt);
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> ParseInts(IEnumerable<string> values, Func<string, int> parser)
        {
            foreach (var item in values)
            {
                yield return parser(item);
            }
        }

        private static int ParseInt(string value)
        => Convert.ToInt32(value);
    }
}
```

But simply we use this to get int values:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var results = input.Split('-').Select(int.Parse);
```

instead of writing everything.

Comment: I will try to build basic syntax from now. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: But last question you are not using delegate, right?

Comment: Why do you need to use a delegate?

Comment: because i got a task to use delegate.

Comment: you do not set the func to anything. I suppose you want `var results = ParseInts(input.Split('-'), ParseInt);`, don´t you?

Comment: nothing is happening even i tried to debug it. i put 123 it comes with 123 and if i put any sign before it gives execption

Comment: Delegate is sometimes used implicitly. When you pass a method name to a delegate type left-value, an implicit `new` delegate type is performed. `Func<string, int>` is a predefined delegate type as `public delegate TResult Func<in T1, out TResult>(T1 arg1)`